# How to calculate the position of point P in 3d space?

Tags: math, vector, 3d, geometry

As show in the image below, given the point O, A, B and the α, how to get the position of point P in the 3D-space?

Thanks advance!
[image]

Comment: This is a math problem, not a C++ problem.

Comment: Take pythagoras' theorem, `dist = sqrt((x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2)` and just add another term for `z`

Comment: @user2896976 actually, I need to calculate the position of P(x,y,z) not the dist, the circle's radius is known

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's vectors

```
b = B - O
a = A - O
p = P - O
```

It seems that the simplest way is using of [SLERP interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) between vectors b and a. 
At first find angle Omega between vectors b and a (for example, through dot product), then apply SLERP

```
p = Sin(Omega - Alpha) * b / Sin(Omega) + Sin(Alpha) * a / Sin(Omega)
```

---

Alternative way - you can find vector of rotation axis (normal to the circle plane) as

```
k = b x a //vector product
k = k.Normalized  //unit vector
```

and then use [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula) to get `p=P-O` vector

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think the SLERP is what I need. BTW, in my case, the omega is 90 degree, but how can i determine the relation of alpha, a and b. In other word, the p could be "Sin(Omega - Alpha) * b / Sin(Omega) + Sin(Alpha) * a / Sin(Omega)" or "Sin(Omega - Alpha) * a / Sin(Omega) + Sin(Alpha) * b / Sin(Omega)". Am I right?

Comment: For rotation from b to a - the first variant (like mine). Checking is simple - for alpha=0 p will equal to b, for alpha=90 p will equal to a.

Comment: That is great. Thanks a lot.